# Magento 2 - Cannot find field "newsletter_enabled" on type StoreConfig pwa-studio

Tags: magento2, frontend, pwa, pwa-studio

I have installed pwa-studio by following magento pwa docs. Now when I try to run command "**yarn run watch**" got below error

```
$ webpack-dev-server --progress --color --env.mode development
As of version 12.1.0, PWA Studio requires the appropriate PWA metapackage to be installed on the backend.
For more information, refer to the 12.1.0 release notes here: https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio/releases/tag/v12.1.0
Error: Cannot query field "newsletter_enabled" on type "StoreConfig". (... 1 errors total)
    at /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/htdocs/pwa-studio/node_modules/@magento/pwa-buildpack/lib/Utilities/graphQL.js:54:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async module.exports (/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/htdocs/pwa-studio/webpack.config.js:62:29)
```

I already installed metapackage still this issue happening. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

**Magento version: 2.4.1**

**Php: 7.3**

Comment: did you find the solution for this?

Comment: Not actually. I ended up using Magento 2.4.3 and php version 7.4 and that solved the issue.

Comment: I have cloned my cloud magento in my localhost. So do I need to give my cloud instance URL or my local URL in the .env file?

Comment: @biplabrout whichever you want to use as your backend.

Comment: In PWA I am using product recommendations. But environment id, store view code are empty. Any reason ?

Answer (score 1):

Run the below command in Magento root which is defined in the .env file of the PWA setup

```
composer require magento/pwa

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a RCA and updated the configuration accordingly and an issue got resolved.

Actually Magento looking the newsletter_enabled value from the core_config_data table (newsletter/general/active). If the entry does not exist in the table then we will face the above issue.

[image]

So simply go to Stores > Configuration > Customers > Newsletter enable/disable the configuration once and make sure the above entry added in the core_config_data table. That's It.

[image]

[image]